# How to make a local website update automatically during development

Tags: html, css, ajax

I was just wondering because it would make life easier for me.

Is it possible to make a website automatically update whilst programming it.

So for example if i was coding with Notepad++ it would automatically update and display it in chrome.

Comment: Reload the page automatically using settimeout, if you feel boaring to press F5.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to do that using http://livereload.com/. If you are working with preprocessor, then [Prepros](http://alphapixels.com/prepros/) or [Codekit](http://incident57.com/codekit/) will be your choice. Both of them support live reload.

Answer (score 0):

There is an addon: http://fossil.2of4.net/npp_preview/home for notepad++. There are numerous other solutions but you have to find a program that fits your needs. An easy google search on 'html live preview' will list a lot.